# Merging multiple xml files into one using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, ant, merge

So I have been attempting to write an xslt file that takes me three xml files as input and merges them into one, eventually I do need specific items to be taken from each file to display it nicer but for now I simply need it to merge.

Here is my current xslt file but I can't get it to work:

```
<xsl:param name="docs" as="xs:string*"/>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:template match="collection">
    <Body>
      <xsl:copy-of select="${basedir}/../DFHMEAC*.xml"/>
    </Body>
</xsl:template>
```

It's a very simple xslt but I'm currently getting told the "xsl:param" is not bound, I have tried many other variations of this xslt but have had various issues.

The format of the files is in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>DFHAC2001
    date
    time
    applid 事务'
    tranid'无法识别。检查事务名是否正确。
DFHAC2002
    date
    time
    applid 要使用此事务
    tranid，必须登录或具有正确的安全级别
```

The aim is to have these displayed along with the english translations as well as other languages that are in individual files for the language.

This xslt is called by a build xml file that runs a "merge" target shown below (Ignore the description that's for a different target just haven't got round to changing it yet).

```
<target name="merge" description="Extracts the necessary messages from ./CCMF">

    <!-- Clean ./extracts directory for each test -->
    <delete dir="${basedir}/../merged" failonerror="false" />
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/../merged" />

    <!-- Merge the extracted files together to form one output file -->
    <xslt basedir="${basedir}/../extracts" includes="DFHMEAC*.xml" destdir="${basedir}/../merged" extension=".xml" style="${basedir}/../XSLT/merge.xslt" />

</target>
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I am quite a novice with xslt.

Comment: Your current "xslt file" is not even a well-formed XML document, at least not the snippet you have posted, as the XML declaration `<?xml...?>` needs to be the first thing, then you need a root element `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` containing elements like `xsl:param` and `xsl:template`. The snippet showing the format of input files has an XML declaration but not any root element, so it is also not XML. If that build file is an Ant build file you might want to add a tag for Ant, otherwise for the build system you use.

Comment: The inputs files are an extracted form of the original xml but with everything I don't need taken out, stripped down to the bare bones. I will alter the xslt to fit the format you're saying to here though and see what that changes